# How to monitor queries in Azure mobile services?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

The following video demonstrates how to monitor sql queries done by EF in an MVC application:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Implementing-Entity-Framework-with-MVC/01

They recommend glimpse for mvc5:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc5/

I can not find glimpse for Azure mobile services so what is the best way to monitor sql queries in Azure mobile services?

Answer (score 0):

Open Azure Management Portal for your Database, login and open performance tab.
There you get some basic monitoring data about your queries.

You can query sys.dm_exec_query_stats table in your database too, to create custom reports about your queries.

Comment: You might also find this article helpful: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-sql-scale-guidance/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind third-party services, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - it has special support for SQL Azure and a free plan.
When monitoring SQL Azure databases, it will show you top 10 queries, connections, logs, performance characteristics and allow you to create your own SQL-based metrics.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the product